# Postgres do array agg for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which will take jobs_locum_hospital_ids from my doctor table, it will then join this to the hospital table on id and fetch the name, then placing all of these into an array.

so `[187,123]` --> `("George Eliot Hospital - Acute Services"),("Good Hope Hospital")`

```
select array_agg(t)
        from (
        select h.name from (select jsonb_array_elements_text(d.jobs_locum_hospital_ids)::int as id  from doctor d
        where d.id = 11720) as q1
        left join hospital h on h.id = q1.id
                )t
```

But this is only performing this for `where d.id = 11720`
What I'd like to do is do this for each row. So in a way joining to

```
select * from doctor
left join that thing above
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to figure out your data structure or why you are using json functions for this.  From what I can tell, doctors have an array of hospital ids and you want the names:

```
select d.*,
       (select array_agg(h.name)
        from unnest(d.jobs_locum_hospital_ids) dh join
             hospital h 
             on dh = h.id
       ) as hospital_names
from doctors;
```

Just the fact that you want to do this suggests that you really want a junction table, `doctorHospitals` with one row per doctor and per hospital.